# Is there a better way to do this using lambda and rxjava?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a list of ruleInfos and I want to return a list of rule infos of a type after performing some parsing on them, I wanted to know is there a more cleaner way to this?

```
  public List<RuleInfo> load(RuleType ruleType) {
    return fetchRuleInfo(ruleType).stream()
        .map(ruleInfo -> parseRuleInfo(ruleInfo, ruleType))
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
  }

  private RuleInfo parseRuleInfo(DetailedRuleInfo ruleInfo, RuleInfo ruleType) {
    switch (RuleType) {
      case APPLE:
        return new AppleRuleHandler(ruleInfo);
      case MANGO:
        return new MangoRuleHandler(ruleInfo);
      case BANANA:
        return new BananaRuleHandler(ruleInfo);
      default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + ruleType);
    }
  }
```

Comment: how do you measure `better`?  what characteristic should change doing it `better`?

Comment: I personally would want to remove these switch case statements, and would prefer neater lambdas instead.

Comment: you could register a list of Handlers and filter this list: `List<Handler> handlers...` each handle could provides a filter method `boolean matches(RuleType rt)`. Each handler would provide a `createRule(RuleInfo i)`:  `fetchRuleInfo(ruleType).stream().map(handlers.findAny(Handler::matches).createRule()).collect()` (simplified)